# Linking C++ application for RL78/G13: Missing Symbols

Tags: c++, linker, ld

I'm trying to build a C++ program for the Renesas RL78/G13 series of MCUs. I was previously using the IAR toolchain without a problem but now I want to use the GNU RL78 toolchain so I can use some Renesas libraries.

My problem is that I now cannot get the program to link, seemingly because of missing symbols. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Here's the console output from the linker:

```
'Invoking: Linker'
'Building target:'
rl78-elf-ld -o "firmware_2.x" -T"C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug\firmware_2_HardwareDebug_auto.gsi" -T"C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug\LinkerSubCommand.tmp"    libfirmware_2.a  -M=firmware_2.map -e_PowerON_Reset -L"C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\lib" -L"C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug" -L"C:\Renesas\e2studio\GNURL7~1.01-\rl78-elf\rl78-elf\lib" -L"C:\Renesas\e2studio\GNURL7~1.01-\rl78-elf\lib\gcc\rl78-elf\4.8-GNURL78_v13.01" --start-group -lstdc++ -lfirmware_2 -lgcc --end-group
rl78-elf-ld: section .vects loaded at [00000004,0000007f] overlaps section .vec loaded at [00000000,00000005]
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `_stack'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `_datastart'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_romdatastart'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `_romdatacopysize'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `_bssstart'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `_bsssize'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `etext'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `start':
(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `exit'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `rl78_run_preinit_array':
(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `_preinit_array_start'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `rl78_run_preinit_array':
(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `_preinit_array_end'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `rl78_run_init_array':
(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `_init_array_start'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `rl78_run_init_array':
(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `_init_array_end'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `rl78_run_fini_array':
(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `_fini_array_start'
libfirmware_2.a(gcrt0.o): In function `rl78_run_fini_array':
(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `_fini_array_end'
./src/utilities/csv_loader.o: In function `CsvLoader_Create':
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:75:(.text+0xe): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `.LC0'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:75:(.text+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `CsvLoader_Create::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:75:(.text+0x1d): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `.LC1'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:76:(.text+0x31): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `.LC0'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:76:(.text+0x3b): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `CsvLoader_Create::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:76:(.text+0x40): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `.LC2'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:77:(.text+0x56): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `.LC0'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:77:(.text+0x60): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `CsvLoader_Create::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:77:(.text+0x65): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `.LC3'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:78:(.text+0x79): relocation truncated to fit: R_RL78_DIR16S against `.LC0'
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug/../src/utilities/csv_loader.cpp:78:(.text+0x83): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
libfirmware_2.a(mcount.o): In function `_monstartup':
(.text+0x67b): undefined reference to `ffs'
libfirmware_2.a(printf.o): In function `_printf_r':
(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `_vfprintf_r'
libfirmware_2.a(printf.o): In function `printf':
(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `_vfprintf_r'
libfirmware_2.a(snprintf.o): In function `_snprintf_r':
(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `_svfprintf_r'
libfirmware_2.a(snprintf.o): In function `snprintf':
(.text+0x165): undefined reference to `_svfprintf_r'
libfirmware_2.a(sprintf.o): In function `_sprintf_r':
(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `_svfprintf_r'
libfirmware_2.a(sprintf.o): In function `sprintf':
(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `_svfprintf_r'
libfirmware_2.a(vfiprintf.o): In function `_vfiprintf_r':
(.text+0x1bed): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(vfiprintf.o): In function `_vfiprintf_r':
(.text+0x1c83): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(wsetup.o): In function `__swsetup_r':
(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(calloc.o): In function `calloc':
(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `_calloc_r'
libfirmware_2.a(fflush.o): In function `__sflush_r':
(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(findfp.o): In function `__sfmoreglue':
(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
libfirmware_2.a(fvwrite.o): In function `__sfvwrite_r':
(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
libfirmware_2.a(fvwrite.o): In function `__sfvwrite_r':
(.text+0x2de): undefined reference to `_realloc_r'
libfirmware_2.a(fvwrite.o): In function `__sfvwrite_r':
(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(makebuf.o): In function `__smakebuf_r':
(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
libfirmware_2.a(malloc.o): In function `malloc':
(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
libfirmware_2.a(malloc.o): In function `free':
(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(reent.o): In function `cleanup_glue':
(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(reent.o): In function `_reclaim_reent':
(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(reent.o): In function `_reclaim_reent':
(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(reent.o): In function `_reclaim_reent':
(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `_free_r'
libfirmware_2.a(reent.o):(.text+0x172): more undefined references to `_free_r' follow
C:\Projects\ms_monitor\firmware_2\HardwareDebug\libfirmware_2.a(realloc.o): In function `realloc':
(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `_realloc_r'
make: *** [firmware_2.x] Error 1
```

Comment: You can find which libraries have missing symbols by running `nm $LIBNAME | fgrep $SYMBOL` on all your libraries.

Comment: I'm running on Windows, so I cannot use `grep`. Even if I was to run this command, what would that show me and how would I move forward? I'm confused more for the fact that these seem to be "systemy" functions like `malloc` and `printf`?

Comment: Surely you can, there are several implementations of U**x tools available. Install cygwin and grep away. If you find these symbols in some library, you can pass that library to the linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered after a lot of support from the KPIT GNU team.

I had incorrect linker files for the processor that I was trying to compile for (as in, the linker file was correct but its contents not). Not only that, some missing symbols depended on how the workspace was configured.

If you see this problem yourself, the first step is to contact KPIT GNU, as I would not have known that there was a problem with the files without asking them.